# Effective C++, Third edition: Overloading const function

Tags: c++, constants

i'm trying to learn some best practices for C++ coding with the book "Effective C++, Third edition".

In item 3, the authors talk about `const` in member functions.
They give an example class for which they overload the `[]` operator twice - once for non-const and once for const objects.
The following code is given:

```
class TextBlock {
public:
 ...
 const char&                                       // operator[] for
 operator[](const std::size_t position) const      // const objects
 { return text[position]; }
 char&                                             // operator[] for
 operator[](const std::size_t position) const      // non-const objects
 { return text[position]; }
private:
   std::string text;
};
```

---

```
TextBlock tb("Hello");
std::cout << tb[0];                   // calls non-const
                                      // TextBlock::operator[]
const TextBlock ctb("World");
std::cout << ctb[0];                  // calls const TextBlock::operator[]
```

So i tried to implement this snippet just to get some practice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class text_block
{
    public:
        text_block(const std::string& s);
        const char& operator[](const std::size_t position) const;
        char& operator[](const std::size_t position) const;
    private:
        std::string s;
};

text_block::text_block(const std::string& s) : s(s) {}

const char& text_block::operator[](const std::size_t position) const
{
    return s[position];
}

char& text_block::operator[](const std::size_t position) const
{
    return s[position];
}

int main()
{
    text_block tb("non-const");
    const text_block ctb("const");

    std::cout << tb[0] << std::endl << ctb[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, `g++ 6.1.1` gives me several errors, e.g., `error: ‘char& text_block::operator[](std::size_t) const’ cannot be overloaded`.

As I understood the explanations from the book, both implementations of the `[]` operator should distinguish the behavior between `const` and non-`const` objects of `text_block`. Therefore, shouldn't the `const` modifier be omitted at the end of the signature for the non-`const` version? Is this a mistake in the book or am I missing something?

Kind regards,
Gunnar

Comment: You have an extra `const` for the overload returning `char&`.

Comment: hmm.  looks like it is a typo in the book.  `char& operator[](const std::size_t position) const` should not be `const`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specified *both* overloads as `const`

```
    const char& operator[](const std::size_t position) const;
    char& operator[](const std::size_t position) const;
```

Just remove the `const` specifier from the one that shouldn't be `const`.

```
    const char& operator[](const std::size_t position) const;
    char& operator[](const std::size_t position);
```

You get an error, because both overloads have matching parameters (for the purpose of overload resolution). Therefore it's considered a redefinition.

Comment: because it says so in the book :) so it's just a mistake there?

Comment: @gunnar.s Yes, a typo on Scott Meyers' part. Still an excellent book though.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `const` qualifier from the operator definition

```
char& text_block::operator[](const std::size_t position) const
                                                         ^^^^^
{
    return s[position];
}
```

and write

```
char& text_block::operator[](const std::size_t position)
{
    return s[position];
}
```

Also there is no need to specify the const qualifier for the parameter. It is just simpler to write

```
char& text_block::operator[](std::size_t position)
{
    return s[position];
}
```

Otherwise there are two operators that differ only by the return type

```
const char& text_block::operator[](const std::size_t position) const
^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return s[position];
}

char& text_block::operator[](const std::size_t position) const
^^^^^
{
    return s[position];
}
```

You may not overload functions by their return type.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error in the 14th printing of the 3rd edition of Effective C++.  See Scott Meyers' [errata page](http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/ec++3e-errata.html).

```
    DATE                                                                  DATE
  REPORTED WHO PAGES  WHAT                                                FIXED
  -------- --- -----  ------------------------------------------------  --------
   6/17/14 tsc    20  Near top of page, second operator[] should not    8/17/15
                      be declared const. (This error originated in
                      the 14th printing.)
```